# Different ways of initializing a Model for a View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, memory

How much is the actual memory / performance gain in an ASP.NET MVC controller when using these two different ways of declaring the Model for a view?

```
User user = userService.GetByID(id);
return View(user);
```

or

```
return View(userService.GetById(id));
```

I'm supposing that the last one is a bit more performant as we do not initialize an object, however the first one is more readable. Would this even matter on a webserver with thousands of visitors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you initialize an object in both cases; what the first is doing that the second is not is: 1) reserve some space for a variable (which doesn't concern performance, but space); 2) add a reference to the object (that is, increment the number of references for that object) and then remove the reference (decrement the number of references) the row after.

I would hardly believe that a performance difference is observable between the two.

That said, I prefer the second, as there's no need for the `user` variable, there; anyway, it's just a matter of taste, there may be styling reasons to prefer the first and other ones to prefer the second.

Comment: well, I don't know if `userService.GetById` creates an object or returns an existing one, but I hope I made myself clear...

Answer (score 4):

There is zero difference between the two statements as far as what memory is allocated, and the behavior of the garbage collector.  Use the one you prefer to read :-)